# Grails and Oauth2 Spring security

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jackson

I'm tring to configure ad OAUTH2 provider with grails based on plugin [grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider](https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider) but upgraded to [pring-Security-OAuth M6](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?123470-Spring-Security-OAuth-1-0-0-M6-released).

I was able to register clients and get authorization code using /oauth/authorize endpoint.

But I have a problem when I try to obtain access token, it seems it can't return json.

I call the access token endpoint with curl

```
curl -k -i -H "Accept: application/json" "https://graph.mysite.it/oauth/token?client_id=testApp&client_secret=testAppSecret&response_type=token&grant_typization_code&code=OJD7xf&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.mysiste.it%2Fxme"
```

And server reply with HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException Could not find acceptable representation.

Searching on google I have tried adding in resources.xml mvc:annotation-driven to
let spring register json jackson convertor, at this point the call return with HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers"

Going into spring security oauth source I reached this controller [TokenEndpoint.java](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/blob/065e68a1451467b5ec51098409e4c89f8b87ae39/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.java)
Debugging here I see the token is correctly generated.
Using groovy console I have tried manually colling jackson converter ad it worked:

```
   import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
   import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken
   def mapper = new ObjectMapper()
   def token = new OAuth2AccessToken('fdkshdlfhklsahdklfhksaldfkl')
   mapper.writeValueAsString(token)
```

The json is correctly printed, so I can exclude a problem in jackson configuration.

The spring mvc controller is mapped in grails with

"/oauth/token"(uri:"/oauth/token.dispatch")

Where the problem is? Why grails can't return the json?

This is my [Dependecy report](http://pastebin.com/xFxubqUj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

In Spring the converters are declared in bean RequestMappingHandlerAdapter that was configured in grails core in file ControllersGrailsPlugin.

Declaring  in resource.xml has no effect.

To add converters I have redefined the bean in a doWithSpring method of my grails plugin

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
import org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter


class MyGrailsPlugin {

def doWithSpring = {
annotationHandlerAdapter(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter){
            messageConverters = [
                new StringHttpMessageConverter(writeAcceptCharset: false),
                new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter(),
                new FormHttpMessageConverter(),
                new SourceHttpMessageConverter(),
                new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter()
                ]
            }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, but declared annotationHandlerAdapter configuration in resource.groovy this way and it works:

```
import org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter

beans = {
    annotationHandlerAdapter(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter){
        messageConverters = [
                new StringHttpMessageConverter(writeAcceptCharset: false),
                new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter(),
                new FormHttpMessageConverter(),
                new SourceHttpMessageConverter(),
                new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter()
        ]
    }

}
```